What is the difference between desc and desc table command?
desc tablename;

and
desc table tablename;

are giving different outputs.what is the difference?
i wanted to see the structure of the table,but accidentally ended up using desc table command and it led me to a completely different output

desc tablename; describes the table - its columns and indices.
desc table tablename; describes a query table tablename;, i.e. it is explain select * from tablename;

Great. Its applicable only for mysql and Not for Mariadb...

@IndraKumarS o_O The question is tagged as MySQL-related only. i see nothing about MariaDB (which does not implement TABLE statement) in it..

Yes. Thats what i also analysed and commented here. Im using mariadb. so tried these commands. 2nd one didnt work. then tried in mysql fiddle. it worked as you explained.

@IndraKumarS MariaDB is not MySQL. They are different products. They have a common ancestor, but both products have changed a lot since MariaDB forked in 2010. We should not think of these two products as compatible anymore, or hardly even related.
